# Regular Expression that allows character,numbers with dash(-). And disallow special characters like &, % etc

Tags: regex

I am working on a regular expression for text box that allows only characters and numbers (`A-Z`, `a-z`, `0-9`) and dash (`-`), and ignore all special characters and ignore spaces.

Like `xyz-test`.

I'm trying this `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` expression.It allow number and characters, but how to disallow special character except dash (`-`).

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: i dint try. i dont know about rejex so.

Comment: Why don't you invest in learning regex so you do not have to bother us in the future? If you have a particular question about your regex, then you can ask a new question here. Take a look at [these lessons](http://regexone.com/)

Comment: This is not a regex coding service. You should always show at least a minimal effort. Why should anyone invest his time to do **your** work, when you are not willing to invest time yourself?

Comment: M trying this ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$... this allow number & char.but how to disallow special character except dash(-).

Comment: You already specified what's allowed. You can see your demo here https://regex101.com/r/fQ2zV5

Comment: thanks Dolgsthrasir & moffeltje

Answer (score 0):

Your try `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` already disallows any special characters.

To allow dash, add it to the character class:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-]+$
           ^
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nO9eJ1/1)

**Regex explanation**

- `^` - Beginning of string
- `[a-zA-Z0-9-]+` - A character class that matches 1 or more occurrences of lower- and uppercase English letters, digits or a `-`
- `$` - End of string

Comment: What is the language you are using? JavaScript/PHP/C#? The regex will actually work on most platforms though.

Comment: Does it work? Please let me know if you need more assistance.